# how to access relevant client ID

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Thanks in advance.

I have one user control which has one upload html control and button control. I used this user control twice in one page like 
`<uc:upload id="FileUpload" runat="server" Header="Attachments" ToFile="True" Enabled="true" ></uc:upload>`

and 
`<uc:upload id="ConfidentialFileUpload" runat="server" Header="Attachments" ToFile="True" Enabled="true" ></uc:upload>`.

I want to put one validation that is file size should not be greater than 2 MB. for this validation I have put below code
var filepath = document.getElementById("<%= filMyFile.ClientID%>").value;

Now the problem is, filMyFile.ClientID returns same value(FileUpload_FilmyFile) always even if I upload two different files in two different upload controls.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you put a CustomValidation control in your user control. If the FileUpload control's ID is *FilMyFile* and the validation control's ID is *ValidateMyFile*, then your client validation function could look like this:

```
function MyUploadValidation(source, arguments)
{
    // source is the validation control
    var fileUploadID = source.id.replace('ValidateMyFile', 'FilMyFile');
    var filePath = document.getElementById(fileUploadID).value;
    // Validation code
}
```

It may not be the prettiest way to do it, but it works for me.